# event "if" and click enough 2 buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

i have two button is btn_turn1 and btn_turn2 , i want when user click Enough btn_turn1 and btn_turn2 after event "if" will printf to screen at txt_turn but it just printf "0", help me

[image]

Comment: Don't provide images of text. Instead [edit] to add the text itself! General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 3) You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all JButton in swing can not be selected. it is a button, it can be clicked, entered, pressed, etc.

it is hard to understand what you are asking for, but i assume you are trying to count clicks from 2 Jbuttons and have to display it in Jtextfield. most simple and easy approach is next.

```
public class Cit extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

JButton btn_dahn1;
JButton btn_dahn2;
JTextField textField;
static  int step ;

public Cit(){
    btn_dahn1 = new JButton("Button1");
    btn_dahn1.addActionListener(this);
    btn_dahn2 = new JButton("Button2");
    btn_dahn2.addActionListener(this);
    textField = new JTextField();


    btn_dahn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    btn_dahn1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    btn_dahn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    btn_dahn2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));

    add(btn_dahn1);
    add(btn_dahn2);
    add(textField);
}
```

you can add Cit class to frame or dialog or whatever you use, then click button1 and button2, jtextfield will display the steps.

if you are not familiar how to do that. look at next code part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Cit cit = new Cit();
    frame.getContentPane().add(cit);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}
```

Comment: I know, it is sometimes tempting, but please consider to not honor such questions with an answer. The question shows zero prior research, it uses screen shots. And the OP ignored the polite feedback asking to improve this low quality question.

Comment: @GhostCat  good advice, i have noticed that it's an  image, and posted 2 days ago just now.